# Should questions that are resolved by reinstalling some software be closed as unreproducible?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

If a problem is solved by a software reinstall, is it unreproducible?

As an example, I've asked a question about an [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) bug which occurred after I installed Python 3 two days ago, and after that I had to reinstall Eclipse three times.

All of those three bugs were solved by reinstalling Eclipse.

I asked about the latest bug I had here:
*[Compiler not accepting import java.awt.event.MouseListener in all new Eclipse projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639614/compiler-not-accepting-import-java-awt-event-mouselistener-in-all-new-eclipse-pr)*

Eventually, the question was closed as "not reproducible or caused by typos".

Tangentially, I also had two typos in my question originally, which would have caused the bug if I had mistyped them in my actual code, but I only mistyped them in the question text (I forgot `event` in the title and in the first line), the actual import contained the full and correct `java.awt.event.MouseListener` though, which can be seen in the third edit of the question.

On this specific example, I was able to reproduce the behavior by uninstalling and reinstalling "Python 3" two more times and having the same compiler error two more times, and then solve the problem by reinstalling two more times.

In this case, would the question still be closable as "typo/non-reproducible"?

Comment: It seems "reinstall it" is in the same category as "turn it off and on again".

Comment: Probably yes, I don't know the stackoverflow policies on questions where the answer/solution is to "turn it off and on again" though.

Comment: Generally that falls under "not reproducible". Not always but often enough.

Comment: FWIW, typos in your question that aren't present in your actual code are even worse than "genuine" typos: you're giving misleading evidence to the people who are trying to help you. At least in this case you did fix those question typos. But bear in mind that it can strongly discourage answerers when they have to deal with that sort of thing.

Comment: Also, such as we are talking about it, but does missing import should be flagged as *"typo/non-reproducible"* ?

Comment: @PM2Ring it was a misunderstanding the 2 wasn't for the python version, it was for "2 more times" as in reproducing it more than once, because reproducing it only 1 time isn't super hard evidence of an interaction

Comment: @Elikill58 a lot of times - yes. However, do note that *common* typos are likely useful for future readers. So, not all typos are equal. In JS many people type something like `if (x = 1)` and *assign* the value as well as make the `if` condition a constant. That is a typo, since they probably meant an equality check: `if (x == 1)` or `if (x === 1)`. However, there is a canonical for it: [What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`? (Single, double, and triple equals)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871616)

Answer (score 29):

Questions about the proper use of programming tools, including IDEs, are on-topic. If the question is about a tool misbehaving, then for the question (and its answers) to be useful to the site, it *must* be clearly stated how the problem behaviour arises. Otherwise, future readers with the same (or similar) problem are unlikely to find the question in a search.

If the cause of the problem is some unexplained vague & mysterious combination of factors, and the problem is resolved by the common & generic solution of uninstalling & reinstalling, then it's unlikely that the question will be beneficial to future readers.

But let's say we have this scenario. You say "I installed components A, B, C, in that order, which seems logical, but C then fails when I try to do task X". And the solution is "You actually need to install them in this order: B, A, C, because otherwise B messes up some configs created by A". In that case, I think the question and its answer are useful to the site.

Answer (score 25):

They shouldn't **necessarily** be closed as "not reproducible."

Plenty of problems can be solved by uninstalling and reinstalling the software.  But that's rarely the *best* solution: there's often a better way that doesn't require doing so.  A reinstall is a blunt instrument, and often wipes out settings and other things that make a reinstall tedious.

Reinstalling the software is, in all likelihood, only **one** way of fixing it.  Closing the question prevents someone from coming along later with a **better** solution to help the next person with the same problem.

---

<sup>Of course, none of this means that other close reasons aren't applicable to some such questions.  I've seen plenty with very unclear descriptions of what's happening and what triggers it, for instance.</sup>

Answer (score 12):

Much more often than not, they should.

Managing state is hard. What "reinstall" does (sometimes) is simply reset the non working system to a "basic working state", hopefully getting rid of whatever unknown issue that was causing the problem.

It's not very different [to trying turning it off and on again](https://youtu.be/p85xwZ_OLX0). It's a fantastic trouble-shooting step, particularly for complex system where an unseen moving piece could be causing undesired behaviour.

When you are asking about a third party software, it's almost a mandatory step. Particularly for client software. (And for server software, often the question should be asked on a different site).

When reinstalling is the answer, it generally means that we have no clue what actually is causing the issue, and one is simply recommending "get back to the starting line and see if works"; hoping that whatever misconfiguration of invalid data in the system is purged away.

If the only "solution" is reinstalling, it likely means there is not enough data to properly diagnose the issue. The question could also be closed as "needs details", for example. But saying "this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers" would be accurate as well. Other users could come with a similar issue, reinstall and not be helped, because whatever was causing their issue was completely different from the first question.

There could be rarer cases where the solution involves a reinstall, and yet the question would be adequately scoped and with enough details to be useful to more users than just the one asking them, but then it would mean that the answerer would have enough detail to be able to explain why reinstalling would solve the issue, and what was the issue at hand.

E.g, some imaginary answer to an imaginary question could be:

> Looks like your installation is corrupt.
> On installation, FooMatic v3 populates a data-store on a binary format that's very hard if not impossible to create by hand, and since the data-store is not simply downloaded but needs to be created on your machine, the most reliable way to fix your a corrupted FooMatic v3 is simply to reinstall it.

Comment: So the reason to close the question is essentially that it is unlikely there will ever be a better answer?

Answer (score 2):

You are focusing on the wrong aspect of those questions. The fact that someone can suggest that "rebooting/reinstalling the system" without a logical argument means that the question is unclear to begin with. For example, I can perfectly argue that you should restart the system after installing driver on Windows, since Windows historically require a reboot to make sure the drivers are correctly installed. Similarly, reinstalling a program that doesn't work basically tries to set the defaults configuration (some may not).

I can't suggest that if your compiler or your api doesn't produce the desired result and there's no indication that your environment diverge from the default. An example, you made some changes on your service, but still keeps the old behavior. Depending on what you use, the service may need a restart, not a reinstalation, to load up the changes. Some services don't even need a restart. Suggesting to reinstall for these kind of issues is overboard and some times counter productive (what if you actually want to change some defaults?).

If the asker can't explain what changes they did to produce the behavior they are seeing, basically for others to reproduce the issue, and reinstalling fixed it, is the hall mark of a vague, incomplete, unclear question and that would be difficult for others to evaluate what is the core issue and how to properly address them.